# XML Structure - 1 File or Multiple?

Tags: xml, file, structure

Just wondering what you current best practice or your preferences dictate with regards XML files?

At the moment, I have a system (Java) which reads a directory, loops through the files & extracts the XML into objects. Each user has their own XML file:

user-0.xml --> `<user id="0" username="UserName1" password="whatever">`

user-1.xml --> `<user id="1" username="UserName2" password="whatever" />`

The issue is that de-serializing these files becomes slow when I do a large number. (10,000 takes about 5 seconds on my laptop). I am trying to future proof my system so that it could handle many thousands of XML documents (I plan on using the same approach to write a forum system that could conceivably have many thousands of threads / replys etc).

Would it be easier / better / safer / quicker (please advise) to save them all in one XML file then just de-serialize that?

users.xml --> `<user id="0" username="UserName1" password="whatever" /><user id="1" username="UserName2" password="whatever" />`

ps. Note that I am encrypting the passwords.

Edit: 21:17 GMT 08/12/2012
I have tested this with both a DOM parser & a stax implementation. In both cases, the bottle neck is definitely the File system lookups.

Rough timing's are ~5 - 6 seconds for stax & 6 ~ 7 seconds for DOM parser for 10k files.

Time drops **dramatically** when we use a single XML file.  ~1.5 seconds for DOM parser & ~650 milliseconds for stax.

Oh well... looks like I'm re-writing my implementation of the UserAccount!! :(

Comment: Why don't you use a database like SQLite instead?